# Why do I get "not defined" on all the Excel objects even after importing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop, excel.application

I've got this code:

Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class FormExcelTest_VB

```
Private Sub ButtonCreateExcelFile_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreateExcelFile.Click
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    . . .
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264298/winforms-com-exception-opening-excel-workbook/33264744#33264744).

It doesn't compile, though; I get:

```
Type 'Excel.Application' is not defined.
Type 'Excel.Workbook' is not defined.
Type 'Excel.Worksheet' is not defined.
```

Being unfamiliar with VB[.NET], I thought to myself, "*Self, you probably forgot to add a required reference.*" But then I saw that there is no "References" folder in Solution Explorer for the project (coming from the land of C#, that seems awfully strange to me).

The "helpful" msgs I get when hovering over the rejected code are:

[image]

The first one doesn't seem the likely remedy, and the following ones even less so. How am I supposed to know how to resolve (no pun intended) these undefined types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This still seems bizarre to me, but I discovered that you add references via Project > Add Reference...

I added "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library" and now it compiles.

And View > Object Browser is the path to see which References you have added, I guess; the C# way seems far "friendlier" to me.

Comment: Bizarre why? `Office Interop` is not part of the basic .NET Framework included with Visual Studio and thus you have to add the corresponding library. When you write `Imports` at the top of your code pages, you are referring to already-installed namespaces. Your code was importing what wasn't present and that's why the error. But all this should be explained in the place where you got your code from. In any case, this is a quite basic issue (happening every time you write code relying on external dependencies).

Comment: That"s not what I'm saying is bizarre - that the References are not shown in the Solution Explorer, cannot be added and viewed from there, is what seems convoluted to me.

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: VB does not show all files by default.  You need to click on the "Show All Files" button in the solution explorer.

Comment: @varocarbas: VS 2013 Premium.

Comment: @TnTinMn: That still does not show the Referenced DLL.

Comment: I am using VS 2012 (and haven't changed any option) and you have various alternatives. In the solution explorer, you can right-click on the project name and, in the pop-up, click on "Add Reference". In the part below of this solution explorer window, there are two tabs "Solution Explorer" (the one currently selected) and "Class View"; if you select the second one, you would see the name of the application in a treeview, if you open it, you see "References". You can also go to the Project properties (back to "Solution Explorer", right click and "Properties") and select "References" on the LHS.

Comment: @varocarbas: That's interesting and helpful, thanks; still bizarre to me that the References folder isn't shown from the git-go.

Comment: ... additionally, in the upper menu, under "PROJECT" you have also "Add reference", but I guess that this was the one you found. I think that both VB.NET & C# have exactly the same options.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on Solution (in Solution Explorer)
- Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...
- Search for "Office"
- Click on "Microsoft.office.Interop.Excel"
- Set Checkboxes of your project
- Click on Install and Apply

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes.

- Right click on your project name in "Solution Explorer"
- Select "Add Reference"
- At ".NET" tab scroll and find "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library"
- Select it and click on "OK" button.

That's all.